# [AutoIt]How to use FF.au3 run javascript into page on FireFox

Tags: javascript, autoit

I have a problem when working with AutoIt use FF.au3 on FireFox.
Examples: I have a simple code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function test()
            {
                alert('test');
            }
        </script>

            <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Test">

    </body>
</html>
```

How to run test() function but don't need to click on Test button

And

Test button have not id properties, how to use _FFClick() function with Test button?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the body tag with

```
<body onload="test() ;">
```

and the button's code with

```
<input type="button" onclick="_FFClick()" value="Test">
```